# Is it possible in JS to define regexp that would give false when testing on given text in the end of input?

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I need a regexp pattern in JS that that would give false when testing on given text in the end of input.
For example:

```
/(?!not this text)$/.test("blablabla not this text") === false
/(?!not this text)$/.test("blablabla     this text") === true
```

But it won't work that way! Here's some experiment:

```
console.log("<expected>: <actual>");
console.log("false:"  + /^(?!<asd>)/.test("<asd>"));
console.log("true:"   + /^(?!<asd>)/.test("<asg>"));
console.log("false:"  + /(?!<asd>)$/.test("<asd>"));
console.log("true:"   + /(?!<asd>)$/.test("<asg>"));
console.log("false:"  + /(<asd>){0}$/.test("<asd>"));
console.log("true:"   + /(<asd>){0}$/.test("<asg>"));
```

Gives output:

```
<expected>: <actual>
false:false
true:true
false:true
true:true
false:true
true:true
```

Question:
Is it possible in JS to define regexp that would give false when testing on given text in the end of input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
/^(?:(?!not this text$).)*$/
```

Note that the regex *must* be anchored at both ends, and the lookahead subexpression *must* be anchored at the end but not at the beginning.

Another way to do it is:

```
/^(?!.*not this text$).*$/
```

Again, the regex as a whole has to be anchored at both ends for this to work.

Comment: thanks! i guess, this solution isn't intuitive. i've tested it, the first one failed, the second one was ok

Comment: They both work for me.  Does your target string contain any newlines?  If so, you should use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only test, just:

```
if (!/not this text$/.test(str));
```